# Requesting Assistance: Creating a Responsive Hero Image with Full-Width Page Coverage using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Heyo,

Am currently trying to make a landing page using as much Bootstrap 5 as possible. If its not obvious enough from my code am pretty new to this, so please be gentle.

The problem that am having is making the hero-image be 100% full-width and have it be responsive using Bootstrap 5.

This is how i want the hero-image to look:
[this is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqvzH.png)

This is how it currently looks:
[current looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U2wH.png)

What i tried to do initially was to give the hero-image section a styling of: `position: absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; top:0;`, unfortunately this has the effect of hiding elements that were under it (the gutters in the previous images)

[Its hiding the gutters now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhoF8.png)

here is the code snippet i used:

```
<section class="container-fluid position-absolute" style="top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;">    
    <div class="p-5 text-center bg-image hero-image" style="
      background-image: linear-gradient(#00000080, #00000080), url(image.png);
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: 58px;
    ">
    <div class="mask" style="">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="text-white">
          <h1 class="mb-3">Heading</h1>
          <h4 class="mb-3">Subheading</h4>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#!" role="button">Call to action</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Am not sure if this would provide anymore context but I've added an image of what surrounds that section:
[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5q72.png).

I guess what am asking here is: Is there a better way to do this using mostly bootstrap 5?

Again, and I cant stress this enough, am new to web dev and stack overflow. So if am doing something egregiously wrong please let me know and I'll try my best next time I ask for assistance on here.

Comment: _"unfortunately this has the effect of hiding elements that were under it"_ - that is how absolute positioning _works_ - it takes the element out of the normal layout flow, so that it doesn't influence the dimensions of its parent any more.

Comment: _"This is how it currently looks:"_ - so I'm guessing, you are already inside a non-fluid `container` with this whole thing you have shown us? Then you'll probably need a solution like https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: @CBroe, the link you just sent is actually incredibly useful. Thank you so much!